# SonarQube coverage percentage with jacoco plugin shows zero percentage but hte number of unit tests are seen

Tags: java, unit-testing, sonarqube, code-coverage, jacoco

I have configured a project in SonarQube and the anlaysis is run using JaCoCo plugin for visualisation of unit test coverage .

The tests are run successfully in Jenkins and the reports can be seen in the Jenkins workspace .

However ,sonar dashboard shows the coverage as 0% but the number of unit tests are still seen on sonar dashboard as well .
I have tried using the following properties in command line .These properties are configured in the SonarQube configuration as well.

```
-Dsonar.junit.reportsPath=target/surefire-reports  -Dsonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths=target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml
```

[image]

Comment: Are there any further hints in the Sonar logs?

Comment: Same problem here!

Comment: @Christopher : No further errors in sonar logs as well

Answer (score 0):

do you have configured jacoco prepare-agent? I faced the same issue and have found out, that I missed this configuration.

Helpful link for that could be https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE45/JaCoCo+Plugin.

Or via pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <append>true</append>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>prepare-agent</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Regarding to your report paths:

Which version of SonarQube do you use?

```
sonar.junit.reportsPath
```

is deprecated since version 4.11 and

```
sonar.junit.reportPaths
```

should be used instead.

And how do you create your xml report file?

Comment: Yea ...This is configured in our pom file .

Comment: We are using soanre 6.7.1 .Yea  sonar.junit.reportPaths is used in our configuration